# SQL Server data modification while importing

Tags: mysql, sql-server

In mySql, I have a Float field equals to 4.85

When importing into SQL Server 2008 in a Float field i get, 4,84999990463257

Someone has an idea why ?

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float values are approximations that are accurate to some number of decimal points. Use decimal data type if you want more specific precision.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html

Comment: Do you mean i should change the type in mySql to Decimal ?

Comment: @John, if you want to maintain decimal accuracy, then yes, you should change the field type.